# Regex replace every two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering how to do a `Regex.Replace` on a string every 2 digits.
For example: if the user types 111213, I want to replace the 11 with c, 12 with  o, 13 with m.

Obviously I have already assigned the values to each letter previously, I just don't know enough about regex to tell it to do the replace every 2 digits.

Any help or pointer to a good article would be appreciated.

Rafael Ruales.

Comment: Any reason you *have* to do it using a regex?

Comment: How does 11 map to c and so on? Also, are you sure regex is the right tool for the job here?

Comment: Will the input string contain other things apart from the digits that should be replaced? If that is the case, then it makes a bit more sense to use regex.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't try to use a regular expression at all. As I read it, you just want to take every two characters and replace them with something else. Something like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Map
    = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"11", "c"},
    {"12", "o"},
    {"13", "m"}
};
public static string Rewrite(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string value = input.Substring(i, 2);
        sb.Append(Map[value]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. very helpful stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Other solutions exist if the input string *only* contains the digits themselves. This code snippet will find *all* occurrences of two digits and replace them regardless of other characters. Regardless of other solutions, I personally think this one is very straightforward and easy to understand.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map["11"] = "c";
map["12"] = "o";
map["13"] = "m";

string inputText = @"111213";

string outputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"\d\d", (MatchEvaluator)delegate(Match match)
{
    return map[match.Value];
});
```

Comment: +1 for a pure regex approach that's better than anything else that's been offered.  And if you're running a recent enough version of .NET you can make it even better (i.e., more succinct and more readable) by using a lambda expression like this for the replacement argument: `match => map[match.Value]`.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

I used mixed of `String` and `Regex` methods:

```
// you can add to list your replacement strings to this list 
var rep = new List<string> {"c", "o", "m"};
var inputString = "user types 111213";

// this replace first two numbers with 'c', second with 'o' and third with 'm'

foreach (string s in rep)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"(\d{2})");
    if (match.Success)
        inputString = inputString.Remove(match.Index, 2).Insert(match.Index, s);
}
```

Comment: This code will never change the contents of `inputString` since it inserts the exact same string as it removes.

Comment: @alaeus: edited. [my first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/999d4258-20ad-4ab9-8ab4-3e2c0b135a92/view-source) works successfully.